# Присвоить класс элементу в зависимости от присутствия определенного класса у другого элемента (без JQUERY)

Tags: javascript

Имеются блоки с цветом "N", внутри которых есть текст-название блока = opacity: 0; , при клике на блок он становится "активным" - меняет цвет, И так с каждым блоком.  Как сделать текст - название блока = opacity: 1; в зависимости от класса активного блока. есть код который "подсвечивает" активный блок, но не получается сделать что бы текст тоже становился видимым.

```
    <body>
    <div class="naved"></div>
        <p class="tekst"></p>
    <div class="naved"></div>
        <p class="tekst"></p>
    <div class="naved"></div>
        <p class="tekst"></p>
    <div class="naved"></div>
        <p class="tekst"></p>
    <div class="naved"></div>
        <p class="tekst"></p>
    <div class="naved"></div>
        <p class="tekst"></p>
    <div class="naved"></div>
        <p class="tekst"></p>
    <div class="naved"></div>
    


<style t
   .active {
      background-color: red;
}
</style>



<script>
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".naved");




for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  const item = items[i];
  let txt = document.getElementById("txt");

  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      const item = items[i];
      item.classList.remove("active");
    }

    item.classList.add("active");
    
  })
  
};



// });
</script>


</body>
```

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".naved");

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  const item = items[i];
  let txt = document.getElementById("txt");

  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      const item = items[i];
      item.classList.remove("active");
    }
    item.classList.add("active");
  })
};
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="naved">naved</div>
<p class="tekst">tekst</p>
<div class="naved">naved</div>
<p class="tekst">tekst</p>
<div class="naved">naved</div>
<p class="tekst">tekst</p>
<div class="naved">naved</div>
<p class="tekst">tekst</p>
<div class="naved">naved</div>
<p class="tekst">tekst</p>
<div class="naved">naved</div>
<p class="tekst">tekst</p>
<div class="naved">naved</div>
<p class="tekst">tekst</p>
<div class="naved">naved</div>
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял. -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос очень сложно понять, но вы хотели так?

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".naved");

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  const item = items[i];
  let txt = document.getElementById("txt");

  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      const item = items[i];
      item.classList.remove("active");
    }
    item.classList.add("active");
  })
};
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
.tekst
{
  opacity: 0;
}
.active + .tekst
{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="naved">naved</div>
<p class="tekst">tekst</p>
<div class="naved">naved</div>
<p class="tekst">tekst</p>
<div class="naved">naved</div>
<p class="tekst">tekst</p>
<div class="naved">naved</div>
<p class="tekst">tekst</p>
<div class="naved">naved</div>
<p class="tekst">tekst</p>
<div class="naved">naved</div>
<p class="tekst">tekst</p>
<div class="naved">naved</div>
<p class="tekst">tekst</p>
<div class="naved">naved</div>
```